# Complex filtering with Q() Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have models Order and User:

```
class Order(Model):
    ...
    status = CharField(choices=STATUS, default=NEW, max_length=20)
    referral_user = ForeignKey("app.User", CASCADE, 'referal', blank=True, null=True)
    operator = ForeignKey("app.User", CASCADE,'operator', blank=True, null=True)

class User(Model):
    ...
    orders_for_all_operators = BooleanField(default=True)
    operators = ManyToManyField("User", related_name="admins")
```

I need to filter orders for operators like this:

1. Status: New
2. Operator: requested user or no operator.
3. Order's referral_user: has the requested user in their `operators` field or `orders_for_all_operators = True`

I've tried this code but it's not working:

```
qs = queryset.filter(Q(Q(referral_user__in=self.request.user.admins.all()) | Q(user__orders_for_all_operators=True)) | Q(Q(operator=None) | Q(operator=self.request.user)))
```

Comment: please share expected RAW query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Order.objects.filter(status='New').filter(
    Q(operator=self.request.user) | Q(operator=None),
    Q(referral_user__in=self.request.user.operators.all()) | Q(referral_user__orders_for_all_operators=True)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, later I realized my code didn't show the orders without referral_user and fixed it

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you.